# Using for loops and nested lists in python

Tags: list, python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to add each row of nested loop independently in order to find averages. I am missing a detail which may or may not derail my whole code.The code should compute the average of a given row of scores but drops the lowest grade.

```
def printAverages():
scores = [[100,100,1,100,100],
          [20,50,60,10,30],
          [0,10,10,0,10],
          [0,100,50,20,60]]
total = 0
minValue = 100
counter = -1
for row in scores:
    counter = counter + 1
    for n in scores[0]:
        total = total+n
        if minValue > n:
            minValue = n
    total = total - minValue
    print("Average for row",counter,"is",total)
    total = 0
```

How do i make it so `for n in score [0]` takes the average of each row instead of only computing the average of the first row? I know that `scores[0]` commands the program to only read the first row, I just don't know how to change it.

Thank you

Comment: ``for n in row`` instead of ``for n in scores[0]`` is what you're looking for I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

```
# Sum of a list of numbers divided by the number of numbers in the list
def average(numbers):
    return sum(numbers)/len(numbers)

# This is your data
scores = [[100,100,1,100,100],
          [20,50,60,10,30],
          [0,10,10,0,10],
          [0,100,50,20,60]]

# enumerate() allows you to write FOR loops naming both the list element and its index
for (i, row) in enumerate(scores):
    print("Average for row ", i, "is ", average(row))
```

Keep in mind that Python supports functional programming and encourages the programmer to write [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) when possible!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm currently taking a introductory python class and I have very little knowledge of all the functions available to me in python. I was wondering also, if the program asks for "no user inputs", does that mean the scores would have to be manually input into the code itself?

Comment: Yes, but you have a third option, which can be quite interesting: generating random numbers! The build-in `random` library will be helpful (you can read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html))

Comment: By the way, you will definitely enjoy [this read](http://codeblog.dhananjaynene.com/2011/06/10-python-one-liners-to-impress-your-friends/) if you are new to Python.

Comment: Thanks for all the info! Most the assignments we have been doing called for us to code without using built in functions. For example doing a min and max function with if statements. I wasn't about this assignment so I just tried to write everything out in a forloop as confusing as it may be.

Comment: You're welcome! Well, that's a great way to learn syntax and logic components. It will be like heaven for you once you will be able to use all the `built-in`s.

Answer (score 0):

the statement `for n in scores[0]:` will only go through the first column.

What you want it to say is `for n in row:`. That will have it go through each row, one row per loop of the outer loop

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.